# Differentiating between preemption and manual shutdown in GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to capture the shutdown trigger event type somehow from inside a GCE instance?

For example in a shutdown script I would like to have different actions happening based on what triggered the shutdown: did the machine get preempted or did someone manually stop it?

Comment: That would be very useful in order to re-start a job that was preempted but not finished

Comment: It's possible to list preemption events, try `gcloud compute operations list |grep preempted`. I'm not sure if the very preemption event that shuts down the machine is already available at shutdown time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the best way to capture the shutdown trigger is by checking the metadata server for the `preempted` value in the instance's default instance metadata.

A `curl` within the instance to find out the value for `preempted` can be used to determine whether the instance was preempted by Compute Engine or not. If the value is **TRUE**, it was preempted by Compute Engine and if it is **FALSE**, it was not.

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/preempted" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

That said, you can always check [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-preemptible-instance#detecting_if_an_instance_was_preempted) for more information on determining if an instance was preempted.